# ParentType is not assignable to type T (that extends ParentType)

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

In my TypeScript application, I query the Database to get some data.

I've build my own type system in order to reflect the data coming from the database.

I have a `getData()` function and I'm sure it is always returning some data type that is extending my `ParentDataType`.

Then there are classes that are supposed to get different types of data, all of them extending `ParentDataType`. In such classes, I want to store the data inside a variable of type `T extends ParentDataType`.

But I'm getting:

> Error TS2322: Type 'ParentDataType[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.

This is my code:

```js
interface ParentDataType {
  [key: string]: string | number;
}

interface DataType1 extends ParentDataType {
  someKey: string;
}

interface DataType2 extends ParentDataType {
  someOtherKey: string;
}

class DataProvider {
  static getData(): ParentDataType[] {
    let data: ParentDataType[];

    // somehow gets the data from the DataBase ... and put it inside data
    // this data will always be an array of a type that extends ParentDataType

    return data;
  }
}

abstract class ParentClass<T extends ParentDataType> {
  rows: T[];

  onSomeEventTriggered() {
    this.rows = DataProvider.getData(); // Error TS2322: Type 'ParentDataType[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
  }
}

class MyClass1 extends  ParentClass<DataType1> {
  // ...
}

class MyClass2 extends  ParentClass<DataType2> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the `DataProvider.getData` method you commented:

> this data will always be an array of **a type that extends ParentDataType**

Note that you're *not* talking about `ParentDataType` itself there but a class that extends it — these are not the same type. You have to tell TypeScript about this and properly type the method:

```
class DataProvider {
  static getData<T extends ParentDataType>(): T[] {
    let data: T[];

    // ...

    return data;
  }
}
```

The method is now generic as well and since TypeScript already knows that your `rows` property is of type `T[]` it will infer that `DataProvider.getData()` returns `T[]` in that context.